# .NET 3.5 assembly in a .NET 4 project (WPF C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-3.5, .net-4.0, odbc

Can I refer a .NET 3.5 assembly inside a .NET 4.0 project? If so, what is the best way of doing the same.

I have an ODBC driver which works only in the .NET 3.5 version but it gives a StackOverFlow Excepion when opening the connection in the .NET 4.0

Comment: could you give a little more details about what the function you're trying to call is doing? This smells like the clr might be handling something differently, though nothing immediately comes to mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

You probably have a stackoverflow in your own code, but you're only hitting the limit when you get to that function.
Look at the Call Stack in Visual Studio and you'll see where the problem really is.